# High CPU usage on UDP DatagramSocket threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp, cpu-usage

I'm running a multi-threaded java server application, that, among other things, is receiving UDP packets from 3 different multicast sources (ports), on 3 different threads.

It's running on a recent dual-socket redhat box (total of 8 cores (4 x 2 cpu), no hyperthreading).

The "top" command shows cpu usage at 250~300%.
shift-H shows 2 threads at around 99% usage, 1 at 70%. A quick thread jstack analysis shows those threads correspond to my UDP handling threads.

I am a bit surprised by the level of the CPU usage considering the CPU speed vs the UDP message rate (about 300 msg/second, for a payload of about 250 bytes), and I'm investigating this. It's interesting to note that the third thread (corresponding to a lower cpu usage) has a lower data rate (50~100 msg/s)

I've included some debug code to measure where most time is spent, and it appears to be in the "receive()" method of the DatagramSocket:

```
_running    = true;
_buf        = new byte[300];
_packet     = new DatagramPacket(_buf, _buf.length);

while(_running) {
    try {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        _inSocket.receive(_packet);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        this.handle(_packet);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        long waitingAndReceiveTime = t1-t0;
        long handleTime = t2-t1;
        _logger.info("{} : {} : update : {} : {}", t1, _port, waitingAndReceiveTime, handleTime);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        _logger.error("Exception while receiving multicast packet", e);
    }
}
```

handleTime averages at 4000ns, which is extremely fast and can not be responsible for the CPU usage.
waitingAndReceiveTime is much higher, from around 30,000ns to several ms. I understand the method is blocking, so the time includes both the time blocking, and the time receiving.

I have several questions:

1. am I right to suspect something is strange ?
2. I'm thinking as "receive()" is blocking, it should not "waste" CPU cycles, so the waiting part should not be responsible for the high CPU usage, right ?
3. would there be a way to split the measurement of the time blocking, and the time receiving the datagram in the receive method ?
4. what could be responsible for this high CPU usage ?

**EDIT**: I played with Interrupt Coalescing parameters, putting rx-usecs at 0 and rx-frames at 10. I can now see the following:

- UPD messages indeed appear in groups of 10: for each group the first message has a LONG waitingAndReceiveTime (>= 1ms), and the following 9 waitingAndReceiveTime is much shorter (~2000ns). (handleTime is the same)
- CPU usage is reduced ! goes down to about 55% for the 2 first threads.

still no idea how to solve this

Comment: what does `this.handle` do?

Comment: it does simple handling on the packet: basically parsing the string, and a few computations - nothing too taxing, as demonstrated by the low 4000ns time spent in it on average

Comment: try profiling https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html

Comment: 1. You're right to suspect something is strange. 2. Yes, `receive()` is blocking, so it shouldn't be possible for it to take the CPU up to 100%. 4. I'm suspecting that it's not Java code that's responsible for (all of) the usage, but native code (or some significant Java code that was left out of the question).

Comment: You "think" that `receive` is blocking - are you sure? If it doesn't really block, that would be the most obvious problem to get out of the way

Comment: as per the javadoc: "This method blocks until a datagram is received" - I can investigate further, but that'd be quite misleading...

Comment: @xTrollxDudex *Everything* in `java.net` is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

NOT REALLY AN ANSWER BUT:

One thing I can assure you, it's not the Java code. I did a multithreaded UDP server in Python and it does the same thing, the CPU usage jumps to 100% within 3 to 4 seconds.
I'm guessing it really has something to do with the UDP itself, since I've also made a multithreaded TCP server and it barely reaches 10% of the CPU usage.

Here's the code:

```
import socket
from _thread import*
import threading
import time
def threaded(s,serverIP,serverPort):
    while True:
        try:
            d = s.recvfrom(128)
            data = d[0]
            addr = d[1]
            message= str(data)
            if (message== "b'1'"):
                time.sleep(5)
            s.sendto(str.encode(message) , addr)
            print(message)
        except:
            break
    s.close()

def Main():
    serverPort = 11000
    serverIP= "127.0.0.1"
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((serverIP, serverPort))

    while True:
        start_new_thread(threaded, (s,serverIP,serverPort))
    s.close)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Note:

If you found the answer, please tell me.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have been beating myself over the head about this for 11 years now. I wrote a home automation app that uses UDP to talk to the individual room controllers. It wastes a full processor core (100% processor usage) to receive UDP datagrams no matter what I do. I went and did a full profiling investigation and it looks like it's just how UDP receive is implemented in Java.
I have since updated Java untold times (it's been literally 11 years) and lately also migrated it from PC to a Raspberry Pi 4. Even on Raspberry, it still uses one whole core just to receive UDP packets...
It might be a simple bug that stayed undetected for all these years or maybe there is a reason why you can't receive UDP packets more efficiently. I'm not a proper developer, so I would not dare to post a proper bug report to Oracle.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33863947)

Comment: @AndreasViolaris: It is an answer, but not a solution.
I'll try to recap it, if it helps: The OPs problem looks like a result of a bug/suboptimal implementation in Java, which has been there a LONG time and seems to be platform independent.

Comment: In the Late Answers review queue, it's suggested to recommend deletion of answers that fail to address the issues at hand. During my review, I noticed that your answer contained speculations without evidence to support them. Based on this, I feel that your answer falls under this category and was rightly flagged for deletion.

While your willingness to help is highly appreciated, Stack Overflow heavily relies on evidence-based solutions and is not intended as a discussion forum. Therefore, it's important to provide well-reasoned answers that are based on facts, rather than mere speculations.

Comment: In any case, my suggestion was just that, a suggestion, and it's completely acceptable to have a different viewpoint. Ultimately, it's up to the moderators to assess whether your answer complies with the platform's guidelines and decide whether it should be deleted or not.